# CSS image sprite error

Tags: css, hover, sprite

I'm trying to make a simple hover effect with my submit button

CSS

```
#submit1 a:hover{
background-position: -1px -56px ;
background-image:url(sprites.png);

}

#submit1{
background-position: -140px -58px ;
width: 112px;
height: 33px;
background-image:url(sprites.png);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="submit1">
<a href="#">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Turn `#submit1 a:hover` into `#submit1:hover`

```
#submit1:hover {
    background-position: -1px -56px ;
    background-image:url(sprites.png);
}

#submit1 {
    background-position: -140px -58px ;
    width: 112px;
    height: 33px;
    background-image:url(sprites.png);
}
```

You can see the results here: http://jsfiddle.net/eu3zc/

**EDIT:**
With regards to your comment, when you are editing multiple elements adding a comma.

Example:

```
#submit1:hover, a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

#submit1, a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

`#submit1, a` this means I wan't my CSS code to apply to `#submit1` and `a` at all times.

`#submit1:hover, a:hover` this means I wan't my CSS code to apply to `#submit1` and `a` but only when I hover.

You can add more elements by adding more commas to apply the same CSS code to all of them.

Comment: Thankyou, WHat If i wanted to add a HOME text to my button, and when it hovers, the text changes color. I tried adding `code`#submit1:hover{#color:#000;}`code` and `code`#submit1 a{color:#FFF;`code` but it only changed the color to white and didn't change to black with the hover effect.

Comment: I edited my answer to answer the question you asked in the comment.